# django.db.utils.OperationalError: too many columns on tables_top_gold - even when model is deleted

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I had huge model(>200 lines). I tried to sync it, but got this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: too many columns on tables_top_gold
```

I deleted it, made migrations and tried to sync it again, but error stayed the same. What to do? I don't want to ruin all database cause of this..

Comment: Did you run migrations? `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I made `makemigrations`, tried `migrate`- got the same error

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`?

Comment: You should consider splitting your model and using references.

Comment: Yeah that seems like a good idea, but at first: how to handle this problem?

Comment: if it didn't even build the table in the database just fake the migration (... migrate --fake)